# How to send INR symbol (₹) in SMS string when sending SMS from an online Web SMS server (msg91)?

Tags: curl, unicode, symbols

Currently I am using the following code in a function in the Controller that sends an SMS to the user as soon as he/she signs up.

```
$mobileNumber = Auth::user()->mobileNumber;
        $name = Auth::user()->firstName;
        $msg = 'Dear ' . $name . ', Thank you for joining ₹100! You referral link is www.xxxxx.in/join/' . $mobileNumber . '. Start referring your friends now!';
        $encodedMsg = urlencode($msg);

        $response = Curl::to('http://sms.wxxxxxxs.co.in/api/sendhttp.php')
            ->withData(array('authkey' => '108xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx272',
                'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
                'message' => $encodedMsg,
                'sender' => 'RUPEES',
                'route' => 'template',
                'country' => '91',
                'campaign' => 'Sign UP SMS',
                'unicode' => '1'))
            ->post();
```

I tried changing the code many times. Tried removing the `'unicode' => '1'` at the end of the `Curl::to` function. I also tried NOT encoding the `$msg` and sending the SMS, but all in vain. There's a `?` symbol being displayed instead of the `₹` (INR) symbol in the SMS received on my cellphone. My phone is Moto E 4G and it does support the rupee symbol. :)

When I send the SMS directly from the SMS server panel, I do not face this problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done.
Only the hex code is required to be sent and unicode has to be set to 1. That'd do the job. The code will automatically be converted to "₹" in the received SMS.

The correct code is as follows:

```
$rupeeSymbol = "%E2%82%B9";
$msg = 'Dear ' . $user->firstName . ', Thank you for joining ' . $rupeeSymbol . '100! Your referral link is www.*****.in/join/' . $user->mobileNumber . '. Start referring your friends now! Earn ' . $rupeeSymbol . '100 for each referral.';

$response = Curl::to('http://sms.we*****s.co.in/api/sendhttp.php')
                ->withData(array('authkey' => '10xxxxxxxxxx111',
                    'mobiles' => $user->mobileNumber,
                    'message' => $msg,
                    'sender' => 'RUPEES',
                    'route' => 'template',
                    'country' => '91',
                    'campaign' => 'Sign UP SMS',
                    'unicode' => '1'))
                ->post();
```